# SymmetricDS: Which approach should I use to synchronize specific tables?

Tags: java, database, synchronization, data-synchronization, symmetricds

I'm testing SymmetricDS and I'm having some doubt about which approach I should use to synchronize some specific tables. I have two application, the first is a ERP and the second is a PDV. Some tables can be synchronized to all PDV databases, however, in some tables the row should synchronize to a specific PDV instance:

[image: entity-diagram]

In this diagram, the red rectangles show which table need synchronize, and the green arrow show the column where we can identify which SymmetricDS instance will synchronize. My question is: which approach I should use to do this (bsh, subselect, lookuptable, etc) and how I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subselect router (actually you need three). I only show you the SQL for `Funcionario`, then you'll be able to figure out the configuration for `Cadastro` and `Funcionario_funcao` by yourself:

```sql
insert into SYM_ROUTER 
  (router_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, router_type, 
    router_expression, create_time, last_update_time)
values
  ('erp_to_pdv__funcionario', 'erp', 'pdv', 'subselect', 
    'c.external_id in (
        select empresa.CNPJ
          from cadastro join empresa
            on cadastro.id_empresa = empresa.id_empresa
          where cadastro.CPFCGC=:ID_CADASTRO
     )', 
    current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

When a record from the `Funcionario` table is routed, this router picks all the nodes with `external_id` equal to the `Empresa.CNPJ` linked to the given `Funcionario` (I assumed `Funcionario.id_cadastro` to be the reference to `Cadastro.CPFCGC`)

Note I used `c.external_id`, but you may want to use c.node_id (depends on what you put into `Empresa.CNPJ`).

Comment: I would optimize `select empresa.CNPJ` with `select distinct empresa.CNPJ` in case there's n-n relationship in general.

Comment: @Raffaele Isn't subselect route an inefficient approach?

Comment: No. Later, if you find that your production setup suffers from performance problems and a hardware upgrade can't be afforded, you may try to speed things up by using routing tables / routing columns (it means you have to somehow digest the routing yourself and add columns to store the node/lookup key)