# SymmetricDS: Transporting row from a node to another

Tags: java, database, synchronization, data-synchronization, symmetricds

As you could see in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612547/symmetricds-which-approach-should-i-use-to-synchronize-specific-tables), I'm using SymmetricDS to synchronize a structure of tables. After solving the problem of the linked question, I've found another issue, in the same structure:

[image: table structure]

The red rectangles show which tables need synchronize, and the green arrow show the column where we can identify which SymmetricDS instance will synchronize.

Let's suppose I've created a new Funcionario row linked with specified by Empresa through Cadastro, so the created Funcionario is pushed to a specific node, as expected. However, I've noticed that I linked this Funcionario with the wrong Empresa, so I changed the Cadastro - Empresa relationship. What should happen in this case is:  the Funcionario will be deleted in the node it was pushed before, and this same Funcionario will be pushed to another node, correctly related to the new Cadastro-Empresa relationship. How can I do it using SymmetricDS?